# Having a problem to make darkmode toggle on my website

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web, darkmode

I am currently trying to make an website for personal project and i wanted to make a darkmode toggle but it's not working properly it will only change the color of top of the website
here is my darkmodetoggler code
import { useState } from 'react';

````
import { useState } from 'react';

const DarkModeToggle = () => {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState<boolean>(true); // Initial state is dark mode

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setIsDarkMode(prevMode => !prevMode);
    const element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
  };


const DarkModeToggler = ({ isDarkMode, toggleDarkMode }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={isDarkMode ? 'dark-mode' : ''}>
        <button className="more-button" onClick={toggleDarkMode}>
          Toggle dark mode
        </button>
      </div>
      <style jsx>{`
        .dark-mode {
          background-color: black;
          color: white;
        }
        
        .more-button {
          padding: 10px 20px;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 5px;
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
          color: #333;
          font-size: 16px;
          cursor: pointer;
          transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
        }
        
        .more-button:hover {
          background-color: #b0b0b0;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
};

export default DarkModeToggler;```

and this is my user.tsx with displaying the personal project and i want to know how to display this toggle on return function i've been trying out multiple times. but it only changes the top of the screen where i put the button

I wanted to know what is the problem of my code and expect to see the solutions moreover it seems like toggle does not overwrite the user.tsx
````

Comment: Please post the whole component code!

Comment: @Kyle Lee you have to use redux tool kit to manage a global state for currently active theme. then form your component dispatch an action to update selected them state

Comment: Post a comment.